# Next.js role based access to component

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to restrict access to a admin area based on a int flag called isAdmin that is set to either 0 or 1 in my users table.

In the admin component I've made a function to fetch an API route that returns a unique user based on email, which will allow me to pass this parameter from the session to the API route - but it never returns true value

This is the code for the lookup function and how I restrict access in the component

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const dashboards = await prisma.dashboard.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      id: "asc",
    }
  })

  return {
    props: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ dashboards })),
  }
}

async function checkAdminUser(email: string) {
  try {
    const result = await fetch(`/api/user/${email}`, {
      method: "GET",
    })
    const user = await result.json()
    if (user.isAdmin == 1) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

const Dashboard: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  if (!session || !checkAdminUser(session.user?.email)) {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <AccessDenied />
      </Layout>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
        ..Layout code
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

I've also tried the checkAdminUser function as a Promise without success. The API route has been checked for valid output

> "{"id":1,"image":null,"name":null,"email":"censoredfor@crawlers.com","emailVerified":null,"isAdmin":1,"createdAt":"2022-09-21T07:52:20.263Z","updatedAt":"2022-09-21T10:22:39.024Z"}"

Any tips to get me rolling would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: when you console.log(user), what do you get?

Comment: No output, and when I remove await from result.json(), I get an error saying "Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'."

Typescript is new territory for me, but my best guess is a missing props interface where I have to declare user.isAdmin as a number?

Comment: I also dk much about typescript but problem maybe caused here: !checkAdminUser(session.user?.email)
this is an async function and we need to wait for it's response. So it might be good to take it out of if condition. run the function, await for it's response then use the result in if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that `console.log(user)` gives you: `{"id":1,"image":null,"name":null,"email":"censoredfor@crawlers.com","emailVerified":null,"isAdmin":1,"createdAt":"2022-09-21T07:52:20.263Z","updatedAt":"2022-09-21T10:22:39.024Z"}`

Then you should better handle how you check if the user is an Admin. `checkAdminUser` returns a promise that is not resolved when you're checking for the value. A better solution would be to use react state to manage access to a specific component:

```js
const Dashboard: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  const [isAdmin, setAdmin] = useState(false)

  const checkAdminUser = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await fetch(`/api/user/${session?.user?.email}`, {
        method: 'GET',
      })
      const user = await result.json()
      if (user.isAdmin == 1) {
        setAdmin(true)
      } else {
        setAdmin(false)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }, [session?.user?.email])

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAdminUser()
  }, [checkAdminUser])

  if (!session || !isAdmin) {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <AccessDenied />
      </Layout>
    )
  }

  return <Layout>..Layout code</Layout>
}
```

Don't forget to: `import {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react'`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is kinda simple using `@tanstack/react-query` & an api route.

#### api/admin/route.ts

```js
import { consola } from "consola"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

import { validateRequest } from "@app/auth/lucia"
import { checkIfAdmin } from "@app/db/users"

export const GET = async (request: Request) => {
    try {
        consola.info(" GET /api/admin/route")

        const { user } = await validateRequest()
        
        if (!user || !user.id) return NextResponse.json({ isAdmin: false }, { status: 200 })

        const isAdmin = await checkIfAdmin(user.id)

        return NextResponse.json({ isAdmin }, { status: 200 })
    } catch (error) {
        consola.error(error, `Error checking admin status`)
        return NextResponse.json(error, { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

#### hooks/useAdminStatus.tsx

```js
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"

export const useAdminStatus = () => {
    const { isPending, error, data } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["isAdmin"],
        queryFn: () => fetch("/api/admin").then((res) => res.json()),
    })

    return { isPending, error, data }
}
```

#### AdminComponent.tsx

```js
"use client"

import { redirect } from "next/navigation"

import { UploadPDF } from "@app/components/dashboard/UploadPDF"
import { useAdminStatus } from "@app/hooks/useAdminStatus"

export const AdminComponent = () => {
    const { isPending, error, data } = useAdminStatus()

    if (isPending) return null
    if (error) return <span className="text-slate-500">Failed to load `AdminComponent`</span>

    if (!data.isAdmin) return redirect("/dashboard")

    return <UploadPDF />
}
```

#### admin/page.tsx

```js
import { AdminComponent } from "@app/components/dashboard/AdminComponent"

const Admin = () => <AdminComponent />

export default Admin
```